# Angular2 - Typescript: viewInjector no more a valid key in Component annotation

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

I am working through the ng-book 2 and got stuck with **viewInjector**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'demo-form-sku-builder',
    viewInjector: [FormBuilder]
})
```

> error TS2345: 
>   Argument of type '{ selector: string; viewInjector: typeof FormBuilder[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '
>   { selector?: string; properties?: List; events?: List; host?: StringMap; events?: Li
>   st; host?: StringMap

I am using angular2@2.0.0-alpha.35.
Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

appInjector/viewInjector have been renamed to bindings / viewBindings

[edit]: And now, providers/viewProviders